# Update Data in Parse.com Class

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, auto-update

I'm working on a personal iOS App, developed in Swift. I would like to update some fields of my classes BUT I don't want to do this with the iOS application.

Concretely, to understand, imagine I've a number on a website. I would like to recover this number (parse it) and put him in the parse.com class (without the iOS App). Is it possible (and not very hard to do this) ?

Thanks.

Comment: The beginning of my text has just disappeared so "Hello everyone ;) "

Comment: Check out Parse's [Cloud Code](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code)

Comment: So you wish to update parse from your website?

Comment: Thanks Jack Wu, I'm on it !

Comment: mKane -> Yes, that's my idea (in HTML code) but this is not my website